# Leaflet - Could it be possible to center the coordinates with a set point in the image

Tags: leaflet

[image: illustration]

Yellow is the image, cyan is the coords, red is the centre for both. Coords are like that because that is the allowable area in the map.

Ive got coordinates where the actual center of them is not the middle point of the coordinates. That means each side is a little wonky from the center.

As i know the exact center from the coordinates, could it be possible to anchor that center to the middle of the image where it is the actual center for those coordinates. Would be a blast to just slap it there.

Or could i somehow add a margin towards each direction so with a little fiddling i could make it like in the illustration.

I have attempted to play with the coordinates themselves to make it fit the image, but that feels impossible to make it right, the image either goes wonky or the markers that i add go off their right spots whenever i get one of the edges right.

Edit: and im using CRS.Simple here.

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle demo. Do you want that the blue rectangle is moved, so that the center of it is the same center as of the yellow layer? If not please tell me what do you mean with slap? Do you mean snap?

Comment: So the yellow represents the background image (L.imageOverlay) and using L.CRS.Simple i am adding the coordinates in. The background is square but the coordinates are not square and the true center, which is the overlay image center, is not the center for the coordinates aka not 0,0, but i know the center for the coordinates which is [11999, 9199]. On top of that the coordinates are taken from a smaller area than how big the map is, so the coordinates wont reach the edges of the overlay in any of the edges. What i want is to fill the yellow area of the background to make the perspective right.

Comment: ..continues. Or to just let some piece of code, or a leaflet plugin to align the image and the coordinates in the perspective that they are originally, as presented in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by making calibration points to the imageOverlay, taking coords from those points, adding them into leaflet as markers, then fiddling around once again but with those calibration points i got them centered in under an hour. Still not perfect but i guess im happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is using the turf library

```js
const map = L.map('mapid').setView([52.308478623663355, 19.281005859375004], 5);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);


const test = [
  [15.3369140625, 49.55372551347579],
  [23.97216796875, 49.55372551347579],
  [23.97216796875, 54.316523240258256],
  [15.3369140625, 54.316523240258256],
  [15.3369140625, 49.55372551347579]
];

const polygon = turf.polygon([test]);
const centroid = turf.centroid(polygon);

const featCollection = {
  features: [polygon, centroid]
}

const polu = L.geoJSON(featCollection).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(poly.getBounds());
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

#mapid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@turf/turf@5/turf.min.js"></script>

<div id="mapid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommand to use turf if it is not necessary.

You can use the Leaflet built-in `getCenter()` function.

[getCenter()](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#polyline-getcenter) is working for Polyline, Polygon and Rectangles.

> getCenter(): Returns the center (centroid) of the polyline / polygon / rectangle.

Comment: Wouldnt it still stretch the coordinates to match the image, or the image to match the coordinates if i just slap them on with that?